# MVC routing issue when use url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a javascript file with the following url.action defined within my view

```
var Url = '@Url.Action("GetSomething", "SomeController", 
         new { 
                 area = "", repository = Model.Repository, 
                 multiSelect = Model.MultiSelect })';
```

In my javascript i load using the Url object defined above and get the following url

> /EmployeeRepository/GetTree?multiSelect=True/1

My this causes an issue because the url does not correctly map to the routing config which is:

```
  routes.MapRoute("HierarchyMultiSelect", 
                    "{repository}/{action}/{id}/{multiSelect}", 
                     new { controller = "SomeController", 
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                     multiSelect = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
                     new { repository = @"\w*Repository$" }, namespaces);
```

It works if the url is

> /EmployeeRepository/GetTree/1/True

So i wanted to know how can i get the url to be in the format from my javascript which currently does the following:

```
 staffTree.load(url + "/" + id, function () {}
```

Would it be better to use the route data using the parameters or sort the url in the javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong, but your ActionResult isn't set in routing. To my mind you should add `action = "GetTree"`statement to your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HierarchyMultiSelect", 
                url: "{repository}/{action}/{id}/{multiSelect}", 
                defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", 
                        action = "GetTree", 
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                        multiSelect = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
                new { repository = @"\w*Repository$" }, namespaces);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route requires the property "ID". You can't have two optional parameters and expect to be able to specify a value for the second but not the first. Either specify the ID or make a route without the ID.

You can put in a placeholder for the ID like a value "!!id!!" and use Javascript to replace that if needed. You can also use `Url.HtmlRoute("HierarchyMultiSelect")` to force a specific route but you would still need to merge in the ID.